# Spray IO, add header to response

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

I have (formerly) REST spray.io webservice. Now, I need to generate SESSIONID in one of my methods to be used with some other methods. And I want it to be in the response header.

Basically, I imagine logic like the following:

```
 path("/...") {
   get {
     complete {
       // some logic here
       // .....
       someResult match {
         case Some(something) =>
           val sessionID = generateSessionID
           session(sessionID) = attachSomeData(something)
           // here I need help how to do my imaginary respond with header
           [ respond-with-header ? ]("X-My-SessionId", sessionID) {
             someDataMarshalledToJSON(something)
           }


         case None => throw .... // wrapped using error handler
       }
     } 
   }
 }
```

But, it doesn't work inside complete, I mean `respondWithHeader` directive. I need an advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `respondWithHeader` directive in Spray. Here is official [doc](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-routing/respond-with-directives/respondWithHeader/) and example of how you could use it:

```
 def respondWithSessionId(sessionID: String) =
   respondWithHeader(RawHeader("X-My-SessionId", sessionID))

 path("/...") {
   get {
       // some logic here
       // .....
       sessionIDProvider { sessionID =>
           respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) { // optionally add this if you want
             respondWithSessionId(sessionID) {
               complete(someDataMarshalledToJSON(something))
             }
           }
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: They say that code outside the complete will be evaluated at route construction time, won't it bring undesired effects here? Also I have some `validate()` and `params()` directives currently before `complete`.

Comment: Yep that's right, I just was lazy to move everything into `complete`. Just wrap things with directives like: `params { validate { ... } }`. I prefer to keep all these variables out of the route and call some function instead to keep the route very simple and clear.

Comment: Thanks, I found simpler solution though for my particular case: `provide(generateSessionId) { sessionId => respondWithHeader(.., sessionId) { complete and the rest unchanged, can use sessionId inside } } `.

Comment: Could you update the answer with the correct solution? I need to add a Raw/Custom header myself and I'm a bit confused as to how to do it.

Comment: @djsumdog just use `respondWithHeader(RawHeader("your_header_name", header_value)) { ... your code that completes the route ... }` as shown in the answer. For instance: `respondWithHeader(RawHeader("MYHEADER", "123")) { complete("test") }`